# Do Interlocks use only Finesse Attributes?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Page 250 of *Demon* says:

> The dice pool and effects of an Interlock should be based  on the two
> Embeds. Use the Attribute from one and the  skill from another, or if
> the appropriate dice pool remains  the same, base the game mechanics
> of the Interlock on a  mixture of the two. Try not to make either of
> the powers  redundant in the Cipher.

*So the rolled Attribute must come from one of the Embeds.*
I like this because it keeps the Interlock focused on the right area.
(E.g. I had designed an interlock that was far more similr to one key than the other,
and when it was time to sort out the attibutes I found it didn't make sense,
so I rewrote it slightly, and ended up with a more even and overall more satisfying (in the context of the Cipher and its final secret) result.)

Page 156 says:

> #### Interlocks
>
> ...
> These powers are not Embeds, and so can involve  Aether
> expenditures and non-Finesse Attributes.

Page 124 (sidebar) says:

> #### Design Priciples
>
> Embeds Dice Pool: Since they rely on careful manipulation  of natural and supernatural laws, Embeds always  use a
> Finesse Attribute (Dexterity, Wits and Manipulation) + a Skill (any
> type). Unskilled penalties do  not apply.

So it

1. doesn't have to use Finesse Attribute,
2. but it does have to use a Attribute from one of it's key Embeds,
3. and all Embed Attributes are Finesse Attributes.

Has this been explained or errata'd?

Maybe a house rule like, "it can use the Power or Resistance from the same Category as Embed's Finesses Attribute," would work?

Answer (score 3):

*Interlocks* are Storyteller-created power, tailored for the character in question and loosely based on two of the character's *Embeds*.

> **Interlocks**
>
> Every time a demon learns a new Key, she also gains a new, unique power, bridging her Key Embeds — an Interlock. This power is usually a way to use the Key Embeds she has already learned together, creating a more powerful, but generally more specific, ability. The Storyteller should consider the Keys being combined, their systems, and the literal and conceptual underpinnings of the Embeds involved and design the Interlocks. These powers are not Embeds, and so can involve Aether expenditures and non-Finesse Attributes. However, they aren’t Exploits, either, and so don’t necessarily endanger Cover with every use.

I believe that this description takes precedence, and that you can use non-Finesse Attributes for an Interlock. This is supported by the existing Interlock examples - in character creation there is an Interlock using Presence.

So, I would use the same Category as one of the Embeds, as appropriate for the Interlock's effect.